# What well-known objects have this as their symmetry group?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, symmetry

I'm currently working with a geometric object that has a symmetry group isomorphic to the direct sums of three cyclic groups of order two, i.e.,
$$\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2,$$
so it is generated by three reflections.

I'm wondering if any other, well-known and well-studied objects have this as their symmetry group as well?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure? Reflections don't typically commute. What is the object?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It is the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by
$S:=\{a,b,c,d\;|\;ab>cd \;\wedge\; a+b<0\}$. The three reflections are "swap $a$ and $b$", "swap $c$ and $d$" and "negate $c$ and $d$".

Comment: @QiaochuYuan (Sorry for spamming you, I tried collecting my comments to the one above.) What do you mean by "Reflections don't typically commute"? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Lovsovs - reflections only commute when they are perpendicular to each other. In $\Bbb R^2$, consider the effect on $(1,0)$ of reflections $\sigma$ through $x = 0$ and $\tau$ through $y = x$. $\sigma\tau(1,0) = (0,1)$ while $\tau\sigma(1,0) = (0, -1)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you, that makes sense. The reflections in my case are indeed all perpendicular. I guess this excludes 1D and 2D objects from having the symmetry group in question. Q: Is it also impossible for a 3D object to have three perp. reflectional symmetries and no other symmetries besides those? I can currently only think of a cube, which of course has too many.

Comment: How about a rectangular box?

Comment: @Michael A box has additional reflectional symmetries, through the diagonals.

Comment: Not if all three edge lengths are different

Comment: @Michael, if he insists in allowing all symmetries the box will have both rotation thro $\pi$ and reflection symmetries; but we can decorate the faces with asymetric logos to exclude the reflections.

Comment: The product of two reflections _is_ a rotation by $\pi$ so it belongs in the group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Asymmetric logos will destroy the reflection symmetry.

Comment: @Michael, you are so right. Sorry.

Comment: @Michael I guess the box is actually a good example. I feel kinda dumb now :P You're welcome to post an answer with this, especially if you can somehow use this to say something about the set $S$ (which has these symmetries), as given in the second comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rectangular box will do.
The points $(a,b,c,d),(a,b,d,c),(a,b,-c,-d),(a,b,-d,-c)$ form a rectangle in the $c-d$ plane, as four points on a hyperbola $cd=constant$.
Another four points happen with $a$ and $b$ swapped; the vector from one rectangle to the other is $(b-a,a-b,0,0)$ Which is perpendicular to the rectangles.

The set $V=\{(w,x,y,z)|w=a,x=b\}$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$.
The intersection of $V$ with $S$ is a region bounded by the hyperbola $yz=ab$.
This hyperbola has the symmetries of  a rectangle. It only has the symmetries of a square if $ab=0$.

Comment: I don't follow this answer. I assume you use $a,b,c,d$ as in the definition of $S$? How is the demand that the three side lengths are all different incorporated? What do you mean by the "$c-d$ plane"? Aren't $c,d$ scalars? How do you see that it intersects the hyperbola? In general, could you expand your answer a bit? Thank you.